# In a list of questions on mobile view, the question title should come before the counts of votes, answers, and views

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, question-lists

There's a lot of issues with the new design.

On mobile the worst is not putting the question title first (followed closely by the lack of reasonable font sizes).

[image]

At the very least the question title should be the first content in each question.

Comment: Wow, the new design on mobile is a complete mess... in contrast, `/questions` (still using the old one) looks pretty clean and tidy. In any case you should direct your feedback at the Meta SE post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el?cb=1) (as an answer).

Comment: yes i checked it is horrible and that not only in mobile but there it is even worse

Comment: For what reason must the question be the first content?

Comment: @khelwood i think it will be better to read cuz of how the human brain works usually we start at the top left then move to the right bottom so if we make the title the first thing then make its text bigger than the other stuff it will be much easier to look for a Q that matches the one you searched. my personal opinion the OP is correct it should be changed

Comment: I have no problem identifying the question titles. I don’t really see this layout as a problem.

Comment: @khelwood Because it's the primary data.

Comment: Those who browse on desktop are complaining about the new design and those who browse on mobile are complaining about it too. Who is this design for then?!

Comment: @DaveNewton Seems like your reason should actually be in your post. It is odd to assert "the question title should be the first content" without any justification at all.

Comment: @khelwood Perhaps. I'm surprised anybody thinks it *needs* justification since that's kind of a principle of design and information architecture. I assumed my CSS hadn't loaded properly. That this was done on *purpose* blows my mind.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. The titles stand out very obviously to me. TBH I find it somewhat pleasant that the auxiliary information is clustered *around* the eye-catcher, instead of drawing attention down and away with a mere list.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's not an "eye-catcher" at all, and it explicitly draws attention *away* from the primary information. On desktop, it's (sort of) ok. On mobile it's a nightmare; I won't use mobile web anymore at all. Mobile displays need to be very clean and very targeted.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that *for me* this does work as an eye-catcher and looks very clean and very targeted. Please at least consider that it's not obvious to everyone why the design is bad and especially why it should be a specific other way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi FWIW I ran it by our A11Y person and they LOLed out loud. Maybe it's less offensive in light mode; idk.

Comment: @DB_cont The human brain doesn't do that - that's a learned pattern that is based on your first language and other cultural patterns. While you are right in your assertion about an English site, be careful attributing it to some sort of human universal.

Comment: not to mention that if one is familiar with Japanese manga, the order of strips is a live example of the danger of making assumptions about what is "natural" for human being perception. Also worth mentioning is the RTL nature of many natural languages.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- you make a good point I didn't think about that. And yes RTL languages are a bit different but generally in design it's still considered to make the title appear first and larger than the other elements atleast from what i have learned and this applies so all languages and styles as i know a few languages of different styles and majority follow this rule of thumb.

Comment: @DB_cont Yes, I suppose I wasn't super precise in what part of your comment I was responding to.